# php code error in executing

Tags: php, echo, factorial

I have been learning php code a few weeks ago. I tried to run a simple code of finding factorial of a number. 
The code that I executed first was,

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    $sum = $sum + $i;
}
alert("Sum:".$sum);
?>
```

When I ran this program I got an error showing, **alert() as undefined function**.

The error,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function alert() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SNSFeedbackSystem\factorial.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SNSFeedbackSystem\factorial.php on line 7
```

I then realized that alert function should be used in JavaScript, so I changed the alert to echo.

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    $sum = $sum + $i;
}
echo "Sum: $sum";
?>
```

Even after I rectified the error I get the error message, **alert() as undefined function**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function alert() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SNSFeedbackSystem\factorial.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SNSFeedbackSystem\factorial.php on line 7
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server? The PHP might be cached somehow? (Assuming you've updated the right file.) @Monkey

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Read The Full Question ;)

Comment: Did you refresh the page? Empty the cache?

Comment: @user234461 Yeah, I goofed.

Comment: It seems like the file you have is not saved or not replaced with the current version. Also you will want to echo like `echo "Sum: " . $sum;` to see the value.

Comment: @nerdlyist actually `echo "Sum: $sum";` works. I see your point into splitting the static text from the variable, but you should've also changed the double quotes into single quotes for that magical performance boost. You could also go with `echo "Sum: {$sum}";`

Comment: @SorinButurugeanu well dang all my life I just assumed PHP cared... I guess we all learn something.

Comment: I tried to restart the server, but the error is the same. I also refreshed the page a lot of time.

Comment: save your file, it's probably not saved / saved as a temp file / etc, or you're editing a duplicate file which is not in your (local) server folder

Comment: Even after clearing the cache, I stuck with this error. the thing is I have cleared the alert function and wrote echo statement, still the error shows that I have used alert function.

Comment: @SachinRavanthD Can you see the output of the `echo` statement?

Comment: No. When I try to execute the file, the error is printed.

Comment: @SachinRavanthD Are you sure you're editing the file located at `C:\xampp\htdocs\SNSFeedbackSystem\factorial.php`, are you sure you've saved it (CTRL + S), are you sure your IDE is not saving your files as a temp file somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Now, I copied the code and saved in a file with different name and stored in the same directory. When i executed, I got the output. Success...!!! Thanks everyone for your help. But, This is for testing purpose. If suppose I am developing a large code for a project, and then What to do if i get this kind of error?

Comment: This would either be a caching issue, so clearing the cache would help. But as you already tried restarting the server and that didn't help, i think your IDE is not saving your files properly or just temporarily.